# Is there a car faster then the adder in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have heard that there is a car in the game modeled after the "Fusion Coil" that is supposedly the fastest car in the game. Is this just a rumor, or actually true?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say it's a duplicate, but it *does* answer the question.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to check because my buddies keep pushing that this car exists. Thanks for input though.